# Passing Objects Between Intents (intent.putExtra), with Realm Objects

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, realm

I have realm objects with Primary keys here's an example:

```
@RealmClass
public class Person extends RealmObject(){
    @PrimaryKey
    Int personID;
    String name;
    Int age;    
}
```

The Person onjects are viewed in a recycler view, where the viewholder has an OnClick method. The OnClick method is fully functional, in the sense that screens change and everything inside it executes. However the Data from the specific Person object selected does not pass through.

Here is the code inside the OnClick method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PersonStats.class);
intent.putExtra("I don't know what to put here!");
startActivity(intent);
```

Where PersonStats is the class that will show all the stats of the Person object selected from the recycler view. I've been messing around with the intent.putExtra function but I can't get it to work. How would I go about this?

Edit: I'm asking for how to get the specific Realm Object that I selected from the recycler view so I can pass it through putExtra. As RecyclerView postion != PrimaryKey.

Comment: Sorry if there are small syntax errors, I was using Kotlin but rewrote in Java for the post because more people are familiar with Java. Answers in any language would help, as implementation is likely same!

Comment: Probably reading the documentation of putExtra would help. Refer to the developer docs for intent at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent . I can tell you that you would need to know what parameters to pass in via putExtra, if you have android studio as soon as you type putExtra it should give you an autocomplete with expected params.

Comment: @JoxTraex I should've stated that better, I know how putExtra, works. I'm just not sure how to grab the specific RealmObject to pass through.

Comment: So in order to pass this Object through intent it needs to be serializable, is it? If it is, you should be able to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable) - however if it is not, then you'll need to make the object serializable or pass in specific fields of the object in intent via putExtra for string/int

Comment: Or another way would be to pass the primary key of personID in the intent and then consume that in your other activity and construct the UI according to that passed in personID.